# phpOCR is not working properly

Tags: php

I am creating a data entry web application using phpOCR. Where user need to put the numbers that will show on image. In that purpose I am using phpOCR, but it only detect the numbers that is very clean, but I need to detect the numbers that is blur on the image.

The below image is an example of my images, where phpOCR detects only the numbers in red, not the blur numbers.

On the below image the blur number is 10-30-60.

Is there any way to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to drastically change the contrast and brightness of the image - then, possibly, those faint letters will become black, and the background completely white. The OCR may then be able to read it. But then, some things may just not be possible for the OCR to detect.

Comment: Just tried it. But did not work, even now it is not detecting any numbers.

Comment: Yeah, it maybe be too light to detect anything. I'm not sure of another way unless the phpOCR itself has a "sensitivity" setting or something.

Comment: can you upload the image after you adjusted the contrast?